# The image copied from RStudio is not correct. How is this solved?

Tags: ggplot2, export, rstudio

I made a plot in RStudio. I want to copy that plot into another program. I go to "export" and then select "copy to clipboard." The popup has the correct figure, but when I paste it into another program there are problems. In "copy to clipboard" I have two options: "bitmap" and "metafile."
In "bitmap" the pasted file contains part of the figure and part of the background screen. Kind of like a screenshot where I miss a part of what I was trying to copy.
In "metafile" the figure looks good (it is the right part of the screen) but the confidence interval is missing.

I contacted Posit, but was directed here. I never had this problem before. Any idea how I correct it?
What I want is this:

[image]

But here is what I get:

[image]

I tried to enter the other image, but the system did not allow that. Just picture the first image without a confidence interval.

Comment: How about using `ggsave()` to save to disk?

Comment: Second the suggestion from u/Phil.  Use `ggsave()` to save the plot as an image file and import it elsewhere.  A screenshot (basically what "export" is in Rstudio) gives you very little control over resolution and device for export, whereas you can specify all that very clearly with `ggsave()` in order to get the desired results.  This is especially evident since text scales differently than geoms in ggplot, so size and resolution control are very important for consistency and final result.

Comment: RStudio had been working for me for years in making graphs. I was a step up from doing everything in Excel or SAS. I am on Windows, so I can do the window-shift-s to take a screenshot of the graph as another workaround.